# How to remove tooltip from disabled button?

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have my button which is disabled using ng-disabled, but the button is showing tooltip even when it is disabled, i want to remove tooltip when the button is disabled.

> Here is my Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            personinsuranceid="{{row.entity.PersonInsuranceId}}"
            ng-disabled="row.entity.Sequence != 1"
            ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); grid.appScope.AddPlantoCase(row.entity, 1)"
            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add as Primary to case">
        1
    </button>
```

Please suggest me a way to remove tooltip.

Comment: What about using also `ng-hide` with a condition in order to remove it?

Comment: where to use ng-hide

Comment: If do you want to hide the button instead of disable it, you can use `ng-hide="row.entity.Sequence != 1"` in your code

Comment: no no, not possible.

Comment: Why? `ng-hide="row.entity.Sequence != 1"  ng-show="row.entity.Sequence == 1" `

Comment: yeah, but ng-hide will hide that button completely and i want button to be there in disabled mode.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip is rendered directly from the browser, that uses the os-settings. So with an button it could be very difficult to hide the tooltip.

Instead of a button you could use a span with ng-click to handle the call and ng-class to do your styling. Do not forget to check in your AddPlantoCase() for the disabled condition and do nothing when it is true.

```
<span class="btn btn-default" 
        personinsuranceid="{{row.entity.PersonInsuranceId}}"
        ng-click="grid.appScope.AddPlantoCase(row.entity, 1)"
        ng-class="{disabled: row.entity.Sequence != 1}"
        data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add as Primary to case">
    1
<span>

/* CSS */
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: .65;
}
```